# Print 2nd and 7th lines to a file using `sed`

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a directory of .txt files. For each, i'd like to grab the 2nd and 7th line, and add those lines to another file, which I've arbitrarily named list.index. I'm not sure how to tell sed about the current filename, within the for loop, so what I have below doesn't work yet.

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in *.txt
do
sed -n -e '2p' -e '7p' list.index
done
```

Comment: I guess something like `find -name \*.txt -exec sed -n -e '2p;7p' {} \; > list.index` should work as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, you had told `sed` that print 2nd and 7th line of file `list.index`, not add those lines to it.

Try this:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in *.txt
do
    sed -n -e '2p;7p' < "$i" >> list.index
done
```

It will print 2nd and 7th line of each file `.txt` then add them to `list.index`.

Comment: This worked like a charm. I see now that I can use $i to name the file within a loop. And I can do >> list.index to define the file to print to. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can tell `sed` to stop reading after it's read the 7th line, there's no point keeping reading after that:

```
#! /bin/sh -
for i in *.txt; do
  sed -e 2b -e 7q -e d < "$i"
done > list.index
```

(or `sed '7q;2!d' < "$i"` shorter but slightly less legible)

Comment: While this `7q;2!d` is a genius pieve of code, I wonder why nobody did the obvious and leave away the `for` loop by using option `-s`: `sed -sn '2p;7p' *.txt
 > list.index`

Comment: @Philippos, note that `-s` is a non-standard GNU extension. Contrary to the approaches using `q`, that would also read the files fully (past the 7th line). See also `awk` with `nextfile` for a slightly more portable approach. (you'd also need `sed -sn ... ./*.txt` or `sed -sn -- '...' *.txt` with GNU `sed` unless POSIXLY_CORRECT is in the environment).

Comment: Thank you, good to know! The `man` page usually tells about which options and commands are gnu extensions, but it doesn't say so for `-s`. Also, it still works with option `--posix`. Strange.

Comment: @Philippos, [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) doesn't forbid implementations from supporting a `-s` option. POSIX doesn't mandate implementations to return an error when applications (scripts/users) pass an option that is not specified, so there's no reason `--posix` should affect that behaviour. A _script_ that uses `-s` would not be compliant/portable as POSIX doesn't specify that option.

Comment: Well according to the `man` page of gnu `sed` the option `--posix` turns off all gnu extensions. Well, obviously not all. But as the same `man` page forgets to mention that `-s` is a gnu extension, maybe I shouldn't rely on it anyhow. Thank you again.

Comment: @Philippos, you're right. I should have checked the manual, I assumed `--posix` would be the same as passing `POSIXLY_CORRECT` in the environment. Note that POSIX doesn't specify a `--posix` option, so that option itself is a GNU extension.